# Cassandra could not create Java Virtual Machine

Tags: java, cassandra

I am on a Mac OS and I run `cassandra -f` and immediately this happens:

````
[0.002s][warning][gc] -Xloggc is deprecated. Will use -Xlog:gc:/usr/local/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/logs/gc.log instead.
Unrecognized VM option 'UseParNewGC'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.```
````

I have no idea why this is happening. I did the proper

```
export CASSANDRA_HOME=/usr/local/apache-cassandra-3.0.10
export PATH=$PATH:$CASSANDRA_HOME/bin
```

But still it isnt working properly.

Is it something with my Java version? How can I do a complete clean install of Cassandra/get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

In that version of Cassandra, the `UseParNewGC` setting is defined in the **jvm.options** file.  It is the first setting in the block of CMS GC JVM settings.

```
#################
#  GC SETTINGS  #
#################

### CMS Settings

-XX:+UseParNewGC
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled
```

I suspect one of two things are going on.

1. It's possible that the `-XX:+UseParNewGC` setting is not appropriately specified.  Double check this in your jvm.options file.
2. The more-likely scenario, is that a previous, erroneous edit made to the jmv.options file *above* the block I have shown above, is causing the issue.  As the `-XX:+UseParNewGC` line is the first line in this block, the error *appears* to be here.  The section above is where the heap sizing parameters are set, so I would check to see if something was uncommented or perhaps a quote was not properly closed.
3. Check your Java version with a `java -version`.  Newer versions of Java (like 10 or 11 and higher) do not support the parallel garbage collector.  Also, **Cassandra 3.x only runs on Java 8**, so you really don't have a reason to be on a recent JVM like that.

Comment: sorry, I found the file. Is there anything I could edit in this file?

Comment: The GC-logging area looks like this: `### GC logging options -- uncomment to enable

-XX:+PrintGCDetails
-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
-XX:+PrintHeapAtGC
-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution
-XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime
-XX:+PrintPromotionFailure
#-XX:PrintFLSStatistics=1
#-Xloggc:/var/log/cassandra/gc.log
-XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation
-XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=10
-XX:GCLogFileSize=10M`


Should I comment out the `-XX: +UseParNewGC`

Comment: @hyvbug The other possibility, is that maybe some JVM settings are being configured in the **cassandra-env.sh** file, which is where they were configured for older versions of Cassandra.  So I would also check that file for the `-XX:+UseParNewGC` setting.

Comment: any help in this ? 
i am not able to run cassandra due to above error.

Comment: @SiyaramMalav Made an additional edit.  Basically make sure you're on Java 8.

Comment: I found it at `/opt/brew/etc/cassandra/jvm.options` on my mac

Answer (score 0):

Apache Cassandra 3.11.10 runs with Java 8 only.
In PowerShell set the execution policy to Unrestricted

Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted

Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted

And if you get error related to Sigar then comment that line in cassandra-env.ps1 File under Conf folder.

Comment the below line

```
# $env:JVM_OPTS = "$env:JVM_OPTS -Djava.library.path=""$env:CASSANDRA_HOME\lib\sigar-bin"""
```

Comment: "I am on a Mac OS," so I don't think PowerShell is going to be terribly relevant here.