# Cassandra start (in mac os): Could not create java virtual machine while starting cassandra

Tags: macos, cassandra

Hi i have installed cassandra in Mac os and trying to run the start command- 
$ cassandra -f

But repeatedly i am getting this error :

```
~$ cassandra -f
[0.001s][warning][gc] -Xloggc is deprecated. Will use -Xlog:gc:/usr/local/cassandra/bin/../logs/gc.log instead.
Unrecognized VM option 'UseParNewGC'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

My java version is following-

```
~$ java --version
java 13.0.1 2019-10-15
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 13.0.1+9)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 13.0.1+9, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Somebody please help here.

Comment: see the link about duplicate question...

Comment: Also, same error message as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54414075/cassandra-could-not-create-java-virtual-machine

Comment: Basically, don't go above Java 8 with Cassandra.